# Cannot send commands via Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I'm new to the world of Java and now I'm trying to create a socket program. I created a server and a client, but they didn't seem to work. Now I post the code.

This is the server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPCmdServer 
{
public int port;
public ServerSocket server;

TCPCmdServer (int port)
{
    this.port = port;
    if(!createServer())
        System.out.println("Cannot start the server");
    else System.out.println("Server running on port " + port);
}

public boolean createServer ()
{
    try
    {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    TCPCmdServer tcp = new TCPCmdServer(5000);

    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = tcp.server.accept();
            System.out.println("A client has connected");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            out.write("Welcome on the server... type the commands you like, type END to close me\n");
            out.flush();

            String cmd = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Recieved: " + cmd);
            if (cmd.equals("END"))
            {
                System.out.println("Shutting down server...");
                socket.close();
                in.close();
                out.close();
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                BufferedReader pRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = pRead.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    out.write(line + "\n");
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is the client:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPCmdClient 
{
public Socket socket;
public int port;
public String ip;

TCPCmdClient (String ip, int port)
{
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
    if (!createSocket())
        System.out.println("Cannot connect to the server. IP: " + ip + " PORT: " + port);
    else System.out.println("Connected to " + ip + ":" + port);
}

public boolean createSocket ()
{
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    TCPCmdClient client = new TCPCmdClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);

    try
    {
        BufferedReader sysRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.socket.getOutputStream()));

        String response = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);

        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag)
        {
            System.out.println("Type a command... type END to close the server");
            String cmd = sysRead.readLine();
            out.write(cmd + "\n");
            out.flush();
            if (cmd.equals("END"))
            {
                client.socket.close();
                sysRead.close();
                in.close();
                out.close();
                flag = false;
            } else
            {
                String outputline;
                while ((outputline = in.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(outputline);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

[old]
I believe the problem is with the input and output streams, but I can't understand why they don't work.

The expected behavior is as follows: The client connects to the server then the server send response. The client asks the user to insert a MS-DOS command (or a "END" command), the command is then sent to the server. The server executes the command on the computer where it is running (in case the command is END it closes the connection). Then the server sends the result of the command to the client, and the client displays it to the user.
[/old]

Now the only problem is that I have to close and re-open a client any time I like to execute a new command

Comment: Your question and its title don't match. I don't see anything that relates to remotely executing anything, let alone in MS-DOS!

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: I think it should execute the command

Comment: You can't compare strings with `==`, use the `equals` method, like: `if (cmd.equals("END"))`

Comment: Thank you I dind't know that

Comment: Also, please follow Java conventions; `SysRead` looks like a class name.

Comment: Your question says that the problem(s) are the input and output streams. Please post a complete description of what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: ok I correct that, but what is the problem of the code?

Comment: ok i modify the question immediatly

Comment: "_I created a server and a client, but they didn't seem to work._" What happens exactly? It fails at compile time, at runtime? Do you get an Exception when you execute it, or it just doesn't do what you expected it to do?

Comment: No I don't get any Exception, but the code doesn't do what I want him to do

Comment: The client should connect to the server than the server should send him a response.
The client asks the user to insert a MS-DOS command (or a "END" command), the command will be send to the server and the server will execute it in the machine where it is running (in case the command is END it will close the connection). Than the server should send the result of the command to the client, and the client should display it

Comment: Please tell us what is the _actual_ behavior of your program. Are you able to send to the command from the client? Does your server receives it? Is it able to execute the command? With no details, there's no way we can help you.

Comment: Well nothing works fine... I think that the client is blocked when it waits (String response = in.readLine();) the response from the server.

Comment: Instead the server prints "Server running on port 5000" and prints "A client has connected"

Comment: thank you for modifying the post @Laf... i'm not English, now it's much more readable

Comment: Please edit your question if you want a good answer. You need to fix the title and add the information requested _to your question_ and not just in the comments.

Comment: There is a huge problem NO ONE is pointing out.. In your server, each time your server receives a message, the loop restarts as expected. BUT, when you restart your loop, you also reinitialize your streams. This will cause a connection reset error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server code, you are creating a new socket for every command you received from the client. That is why you have to open a new client every time you want to send a command to the server. To correct this, first you need to remove the `while(flag)` loop in server code. Then you can use the following to establish the connection to the client and send and receive command and output between them.

```
        Socket socket = tcp.server.accept();
        System.out.println("A client has connected");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        out.write("Welcome on the server... type the commands you like, type END to close me\n");
        out.flush();

        try {
            while(!(cmd = in.readLine()).equals("END")) {
                System.out.println("Recieved: " + cmd);

                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                BufferedReader pRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = pRead.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    out.write(line + "\n");
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Shutting down server...");
            socket.close();
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
```

Comment: But there's a poroblem in here to... in fact when I close the client and I reopen it, the server won't accept the connection. I didn't tryed it, but I'm quite sure that it will do that. Anyway I've got an idea in how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

In `TCPCmdServer.java`, try changing

```
out.write("Welcome on the server... type the commands you like, type END to close me");
```

to

```
out.write("Welcome on the server... type the commands you like, type END to close me\n");
out.flush();
```

Also, change

```
out.write(buffer.toString());
```

to

```
out.write(buffer.toString() + "\n");
out.flush();
```

In `TCPCmdClient.java`
change

```
out.write(cmd);
```

to

```
out.write(cmd + "\n");
out.flush();
response = in.readLine();
System.out.println("Server: " + response);
```

Comment: well now a part of the program works, but I think I have to change something in the part of the code where the command is executed Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: one of the problems now is that the StringBuffer buffer isn't sent to the client

Comment: and another problem is that I have to close the client and re-open it to execute a new command

Comment: well for the string buffer... i've forgotten to write a part of code

Comment: well now it seems to work, but I still have to open a new clien any time I like to input a new command, I have to fix this